# Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)_python

Tags: python, twitter

After tweeter scraping,
I am going to do 'morphological analysis'. But an error occurs.

"Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)"

How do I fix the code?
Please advise.
Thank you for your advice.

```
from konlpy.tag import Twitter
from collections import Counter


def get_tags(text, ntags=50):
    spliter = Twitter()
    nouns = spliter.nouns(text)
    count = Counter(nouns)
    return_list = []
    for n, c in count.most_common(ntags):
        temp = {'tag': n, 'count': c}
        return_list.append(temp)
    return return_list


def main():
    text_file_name = '11.txt' 
    noun_count = 30
    output_file_name = '6767.txt' 
    open_text_file = open(text_file_name, 'r',-1,"utf-8")
    text = open_text_file.read()
    tags = get_tags(text, noun_count)
    open_text_file.close()
    open_output_file = open(output_file_name, 'w',-1,"utf-8")
    for tag in tags:
        noun = tag['tag']
        count = tag['count']
        open_output_file.write('{} {}\n'.format(noun, count))
    open_output_file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: 0xC0000374 looks like a Windows status code, specifically `STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION`.

Comment: konlpy uses the JVM via JPype. If it is Windows and a problem with heap corruption, there are really too many possible culprits here. To narrow this down, you can attach a native debugger to python.exe such as WinDbg. It will also help to use gflags.exe to enable the page heap for python.exe, to pinpoint the exact source of heap corruption and print a stack trace. Once you know the culprit library, you can search its issue tracker for an open or closed issue or create a new one.