# Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

Tags: python, odoo

i'm using odoo 10, python version 2.7 and pycharm 2019.3.2
i set script path to odoo-bin, python interpreter to python.exe (2.7), environnement variables to PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1, everything works fine.

NOW, i wanna work with odoo 13 in the same time, i've python version 3.7 and pycharm 2019.3.2
i set script path to odoo-bin (odoo 13), python interpreter to python3.exe, environnment variables to PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1,  here when i'm getting this error in the log when i run odoo:

Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)

i don't know why i'm having this? can anyone help me plz!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985060/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740940-0xc0000374-python has some comments which are probably more useful than the answer here.

Answer (score 5):

after many research i found the solution: it's not a problem of odoo or pycharm, it's a windows 10 problem!.

Go to panel control > Region > Administrative, and on Languages for non-unicode programs, change regional configuration, check 'Use UTF-8 to language support worldwide' then restart the computer.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this answer! I was running Python 3.8 on Windows 10 (x64) and my shutil.make_archive() function constantly crashed without any further error message (except the mentioned Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374)). After changing the windows settings and restarting it worked!

Comment: @Odoo 10. Thank you for your answer, but there is a strange phenomenon on my end. I used your method, it was ok at first, but after running for a while I reported this error again. This is confusing