# Process finished with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374). Python

Tags: python, pandas, windows, exit-code

I'm encountering an issue while trying to run my Python project on Windows 10. The process finishes with exit code -1073740940 (0xC0000374). I've attempted reinstalling dependencies, cloning the repository again, and updating Python, but the problem persists. There is no additional information displayed in the terminal. Interestingly, the project runs without issues on another computer and a Ubuntu server. Other projects on the current computer also run without problems.

In an attempt to troubleshoot, I removed all dependencies and started installing them one by one, testing the project after each installation. I noticed that the error arises after installing Pandas. When I remove Pandas, the terminal outputs a message indicating the absence of the module. Upon reinstalling Pandas, the error reoccurs (Process finished with exit code -1073740940).

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue!

Comment: Try to install an older version of Pandas. `pip install 'pandas<2'`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43985060/process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740940-0xc0000374-python would probably be a more useful duplicate but it doesn't have any answers.

Comment: @Corralien same error